# White background under the keyboard

Tags: react-native

How to remove the white background that is under the keyboard?

In the screenshot below, I was able to capture the moment when a white background is visible.

Shown when the keyboard begins to appear.

In the end you can't see it but it is visible during the loading of the keyboard and it looks bad

[image]

Comment: Do you mind sharing your code?

Answer (score 3):

I am using Expo on React Native but I found a discussion that lead me to the solution, using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in your AndroidManifest.xml for pure React Native projects should solve this. However I am using expo so I had to use `"softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan"` in my app.json right under android like this

```
"android": {
  ...
  "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan",
  ...
}
```

This didn't solve the issue for everyone but hopefully it does for you. You can check out the discussion where I found the solution [here](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/2839).

Comment: Works as expected, thank you. As the Expo [docs state](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#softwarekeyboardlayoutmode), this property maps to `android:windowSoftInputMode property` on AndroidManifest. For those to whom this solution is not working, I wonder if they are doing the prebuid with `npx expo prebuild --clean`.

Comment: omg this allows to have the same behavior as iOS! Thank you dude! <3